# Splitting a string for a where in clause or like clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a value that looks like

```
hh12,mm13,kk14,ll55.
```

I currently split it and use a where value in clause to find records that contain those id's in the string. I now have to allow for a string input like this.

```
hh,mm,kk,ll
```

In addition to the above string in the same parameter. These are two character prefixes to the same codes above. If the user puts in the two character digits, I need to be able to get all the records for the values like `'hh%'` or `'mm%'`. I'm not sure if this possible from a like standpoint. Any ideas?

I currently use this in my where clause

where id in(IN (SELECT * FROM functions.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@ids, ',')

But how would I translate the same logic for the same string to be used as multiple likes when the client puts in 2 character codes?

Comment: Provide the query what you tried...

Comment: just show the code what you have tried or otherwise just put the sample data

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not SARGable. But you could do

WHERE LEFT(id,2) IN (SELECT * FROM Functions.dbo.Split_DelimitedString_fn(@ids, ',') )

That will cause a tablescan though with every execution, I'd only do it if your table is known to be fairly small.

Other than that, you could use dynamic sql to create multiple OR clauses with likes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you should consider using [regular expressions](http://www.sqllion.com/2010/12/pattern-matching-regex-in-t-sql/)? `^hh[0-9]{2}$` would be one of the patterns you'll need to use.